# PostgreSQL time spans

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Trips" (
"TripId" integer NOT NULL,
"DepartureDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
"ArrivalDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
);
```

I need to determine if the time span of one record falls within the time span of another.
For example:

```
Tripid |     DepartureDate     |      ArrivalDate
   1   | 2019-11-13 00:00:00.0 | 2030-11-13 00:00:00.0
   2   | 2020-11-13 00:00:00.0 | 2022-11-13 00:00:00.0
   3   | 2005-11-13 00:00:00.0 | 2006-11-13 00:00:00.0
```

The time span of the second record is inside the span of the first.
How can I determine records which time spans fall into another time span(s)

Comment: So you want to know for EVERY record whether it falls within the time span of ANY other record?

Comment: Please show us your expected result.

Comment: Yes I need to know for every record whether it falls within the time span of any other record
And if there are such records in the table it is necessary to display their ids

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid the dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

This will show all containments:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM "Trips" AS t1
   JOIN "Trips" AS t2
      ON tsrange(t1."DepartureDate", t1."ArrivalDate")
         @> tsrange(t2."DepartureDate", t2."ArrivalDate");
```